# Draw line chart from two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

Hi I want to draw a line chart with two arrays' data.

```
ArrayA 
array([265266., 248146., 262715., 280663., 238083., 270262., 254179.,
       277202., 306039., 281294., 294978., 304122., 351522., 340181.,
       322776., 327759., 310442., 328161., 313920., 355952., 344338.,
       322330., 345088., 365234., 420498.])

ArrayB
array([ 26526,  24814,  26271,  28066,  23808,  27026,  25417,  27720,
        30603,  28129,  29497,  30412,  35152,  34018,  32277,  32775,
        31044,  32816,  31392,  35595,  86084, 112815, 172544, 219140,
       420498])
```

The two arrays are in the same shape. I would like to draw them on one line chart. I tried

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(diagonal,[25000,400000],'r--',df2array, [10000,425000], 'bs')
plt.show()
```

I'm not sure the second parameter `[25000,400000]`, is it for specifying the range of my array ?

I received error  `x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (25,) and (2,)` However, the arrays are in the same shape.

Comment: What are the variables you're plotting? What happened to the two arrays?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is for your y-axis value. If what you're trying to do is to plot df2array against diagonal then you should try

```
plt.plot(diagonal, df2array)
```

(That is if they are of the same size)
For specifying range you use python slicing and indexing